# Adding SSDT BI Templates in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, business-intelligence

I have a new laptop with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and SQL Server 2016 CTP 3.1 installed on it.  I want to develop SSIS & SSRS projects using this setup, but I am having a hard time getting the Business Intelligence templates to show up in VS.

I installed the SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015 from here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx

This installation seemed to work, but the BI templates still did not appear in VS.

After this was installed, I started up the SQL 2016 installation again to see if I could add this as a feature in the installation.  It was not an option in the Feature Selection area.  I tried both the "Perform new installation of SQL" and "Add feature to an existing instance" options during the setup wizard.

What am I missing here?  In doing some research, it seems like these BI templates should be available for VS 2015.  I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in another forum.  This issue has to do with using the "preview" version of SQL 2016.  Use this link to download the SSDT for this version:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429383

Hope this helps someone else...

Comment: Not quite and the link does *not* help. There *is* a version for VS 2015 which includes all versions for 2016, but only SSRS, SSAS for previous versions. You should actually check the [documentation page for SSDT versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx), not the download link

Comment: I guess if you want to split hairs, that page is technically the correct starting point.  Both of the links I posted above came from that page.  My answer just clarified exactly which link worked for me.

Comment: I have trouble even using the regular version. In the About screen for Visual Studio it shows "SQL Server Data Tools  14.0.50730.0" is installed. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, but I still don't see the Business Intelligence templates.

Comment: My experience is identical to _HagelIt18_'s. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling SSDT ... to no avail. The SSDT templates aren't listed in the VS _New Project_ dialog even though the install succeeded and the VS _Help|About_ box lists _SQL Server Data Tools 14.0.60311.1_.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Tools > Extensions and Updates... Under the Updates tab, you'll find Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) Update.

Answer (score 4):

SSDT is updated separately from SQL Server itself. In the past, SSDT BI was a separate project as well. Integrating both toolsets is a work in progress. The [latest SSDT version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx) is the November 2015 preview which supports SSIS, SSAS, SSRS for SQL Server 2016 preview but only SSAS, SSRS for previous versions.

SSDT doesn't actually require SQL Server, only Visual Studio, and will install no matter which version of SQL Server you have installed (if any).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on only VS being required for SSDT.